# how to make a small delay in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, delay

I want to create a small delay so that my 1st set of codes run smoothly.

How can I do that in vb.net ?

**Edit 1**

Suppose I have a few lines of code like this

```
..................Statement Line 1..............
..................Statement Line 2..............
..................Statement Line 3..............
..................Statement Line 1..............
..................Statement Line 5..............

WAIT UNTIL STATEMENT 5 IS COMPLETED

..................Statement Line 6..............
..................Statement Line 7..............
..................Statement Line 8..............
..................Statement Line 9..............
..................Statement Line 10.............
```

Only when the execution of first five statements are complete then only the next five can be executed

Comment: can you clarify? where do you want to delay execution, and when? what is your "first set of codes" ?

Comment: Why would you want to do it ? :)

Comment: what kind of statement is statement 5? runs in other thread? it provide a way of setting a callback?

Comment: What is happening in Line 5? Usually what happens is the code executed at line 5 should tell you that its over and THEN, you continue with 6. How can you guarantee that Line 5 will be over in X seconds ?

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray Thats exactly what I was going to ask to cost

Comment: @Ranhiru How can I know whether statement 5 completed or not ?

Comment: Depends on what statement 5 actually is. Web Service call? Database call? Will you be able to post the code ?

Comment: Its just a line where the text is typed in in the RichTextBox dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to make a thread sleep?

Thread.Sleep(100);

Where 100 is the number of millisecond you want the thread to sleep for.

Also make sure to have Imports System.Threading, which I assume you have if you already have multiple threads.

EDIT: Okay, so you've added a bit of code. Still, this should come down to whether you have more than one thread running, and from your question it looks like it's all in one thread. In this case, statement 5 will always finish first before statement 6 runs. That's how code works. The only case where it wouldn't would be if one of statements 1-5 spawns something on a new thread.

Comment: instead of importing I would recommend just typing Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

Comment: @Gent Yea that would probably be better in this case. I'm usually coding with a few threads anyway, so I'm used to threading already being imported

Comment: see my comment to Ranhiru Cooray

Comment: @Failed_Noob Like I said, code executes in the order it happens. Statement 2 won't happen until statement 1 finishes. Statement 3 won't execute until statement 2 is done, etc. The only exception to this is if one of your statements spawns something that happens on a new thread. Is this the case? I see you have Winforms tagged with this question. Are you making some windows call that will be on a new thread? I think you may need to post more code if you can't answer this.

Answer (score 4):

First - given the code sample you've provided line 6 will not execute until line 5 finishes.  You don't need to do anything; unless line 5 is kicking of an external application or creating a new thread.

Beyond that -

`Thread.Sleep` will introduce a delay, but more often than not it really isn't what you are looking for.

If you use Thread.Sleep the executing thread will sleep for however long you tell it.  But your sample code indicates you want the thread to wait *UNTIL* some condition is met.  Assuming you are waiting on a condition that happens outside of the thread you are sleeping, at best, you'd end up with a loop that keeps sleeping for X milliseconds and then checking the condition.

There are other approaches that are easier (in the long run)/more robust than that.  If you truly want something to happen on another thread and to be alerted by it's completion; consider the BackgroundWorker class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

It's very handy for simple multithreading tasks.  You create a BackgroundWorker and handle it's 'DoWork' event with the logic to happen on the new thread and handle the 'Completed' event (check the docs for the correct name, I'm going from memory).  You call 'RunWorkerAsynch' to start the process and when the 'Worker_Completed' event fires, you can continue execution of line 6.

I hope that makes sense/helps.

Comment: I knew about background process but I wanted it to be as simple as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

should do that.

Comment: Please don't do this without serious consideration. Application.DoEvents() will allow UI code to run, which may include a click event which triggers off the very same code that you are already running.

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker object property "IsBusy" and do not allow to execute line 6 until the worker process is busy.

Read more about BackgroundWorker [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)